# Catching Ctrl + C in a textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Despite me working with C# ([Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms)) for years, I'm having a brain fail moment, and can't for the life of me figure out how to catch a user typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> into a textbox.

My application is basically a terminal application, and I want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to send a `(byte)3` to a serial port, rather than be the shortcut for Copy to Clipboard.

I've set the shortcuts `enabled` property to false on the textbox. Yet when the user hits <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, the keypress event doesn't fire.

If I catch keydown, the event fires when the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (that is, before they hit the <kbd>C</kbd> key).

It's probably something stupidly simple that I'm missing.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Go ahead and use the KeyDown event, but in that event check for *both* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>C</kbd>, like so:

```
if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.C) {
    //...
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
}
```

Also, to prevent processing the keystroke by the underlying TextBox, set the SuppressKeyPress property to true as shown.

Comment: Accepted as it was the first working response. Many thanks. - I did figure it out eventually - see my own answer.

Comment: I know, it's been a while, but for those who will find this in the future: Shift-Insert is still handled, so you need to add (e.Shift && e.KeyCode == Keys.Insert) validation. Also user still can right-click on the field and select Paste... So not 100% proof.

Answer (score 9):

I had a problem catching <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> on a `TextBox` by `KeyDown`. I only got `Control` key when both `Control` and `C` were pressed. The solution was using  `PreviewKeyDown`:

```
private void OnLoad()
{
    textBox.PreviewKeyDown += OnPreviewKeyDown;
    textBox.KeyDown += OnKeyDown;
}

private void OnPreviewKeyDown( object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control)
    {
        e.IsInputKey = true;
    }
}

private void OnKeyDown( object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.C) {
        textBox.Copy();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not true, KeyUp event catching is correct solution.

Comment: This is the only example that worked in .NET 6.0 for me.

Answer (score 8):

Key events occur in the following order:

1. KeyDown
2. KeyPress
3. KeyUp

The KeyPress event is not raised by noncharacter keys; however, the noncharacter keys do raise the KeyDown and KeyUp events.
Control is a noncharacter key.

You can check with this line of code:

`if (e.KeyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.C))`

Answer (score 3):

D'oh! Just figured it out. Out of the three possible events, the one I haven't tried is the one I needed! The KeyUp event is the important one:

```
private void txtConsole_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData == (Keys.C | Keys.Control))
    {
        _consolePort.Write(new byte[] { 3 }, 0, 1);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you all beat me to it. KeyDown wasn't working for me, as I was using break points to catch the events. It worked fine on KeyUp though, hence why I settled on this event.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to catch such combinations of keys in `KeyPress Event` look at this table here:

> http://www.physics.udel.edu/~watson/scen103/ascii.html

in `Non-Printing Characters` section you can see the Dec numbers for each combination. 
For example, Dec number for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> is `3`. So you can catch it in KeyPress Event like this:

```
private void btnTarget_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar != 3) // if it is not Ctrl + C
    {
       // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following: capture the <kbd>up arrow</kbd> and <kbd>down arrow</kbd> events. When you detect <kbd>down arrow</kbd> for CTRL, set a flag; when you detect <kbd>up arrow</kbd>, reset the flag. If you detect the <kbd>C</kbd> key while the flag is set, you have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

**Edit**. Ouch... Jay's answer is definitely better. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's because some change in newer version or because I am trying to use this on ListBox, but there is no `e.Control` in `KeyEventArgs e` that I get from KeyDown.

I had to work around solution, I came up with this (it's not the prettiest one, but it works fine):

```
private List<Key> KeyBuff = new List<Key>();

private void ListBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (!KeyBuff.Exists(k => k == e.Key))
        KeyBuff.Add(e.Key);

    if (KeyBuff.Exists(k => k == Key.LeftCtrl || k == Key.RightCtrl) &&
        KeyBuff.Exists(k => k == Key.C))
    {
        // Desired detection
        Clipboard.SetText(SelectedText);
    }
}

private void ListBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    KeyBuff.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it's not working with KeyDown event so I tried with PreviewKeyDown and it's worked.

```
private void txt_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Control == true && e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
  {
    Clipboard.SetText(txt.SelectedText);
  }
}
```